# What is problem with ionic 4 android backButton subscribe?

Tags: android, ionic4

I have problem with subscribe method of backButton. When app starts, click on android backbutton shows on console.log that I clicked and show modal to exit app. But, if app is full loaded, nothing gonna happen. Even console.log.

Code:
In constructor:

```
this.backButtonEvent();
```

Method

```
backButtonEvent() {
  this.platform.backButton.subscribe(async () => {
    this.showAlert();
    console.log('click');
  })
}
```

Of course is something more, but with this code I already have a problem. On simulator and real device.

Errors or warning in the console:

```
deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.

Ionic Native: deviceready did not fire within 5000ms. This can happen when plugins are in an inconsistent state. Try removing plugins from plugins/ and reinstalling them

Ionic Native: deviceready event fired after 5637 ms

The deviceorientation events are blocked by feature policy. See https://github.com/WICG/feature-policy/blob/master/features.md#sensor-features

deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.

Channel not fired: onFileSystemPathsReady

Ionic Native: deviceready did not fire within 5000ms. This can happen when plugins are in an inconsistent state. Try removing plugins from plugins/ and reinstalling them
```

Answer (score 0):

Something wrong with your deviceorientation plugin remove that and rebuild and run

Comment: Did it successfully removed from android platforms

Comment: search the plugin and see their is some more and delete the android platform and re add that ( You have not successfully removed, that's why it's conflicting when running)

Comment: I removed the plugin, I'm sure that is all gone, but still get that warning. Until that warning i get info that back button i subscribe, but after I can't do anything with this.

Comment: Please search all the files with plugin name to find the leftovers

Answer (score 0):

OK, I solved this. Back button must be subscribe with priority, method: subscribeWithPriority(priority: number, callback). That works!